# Как открыть файл .pak?

Tags: android

Есть игра на android. В файлах игры есть файлы **.pac**, в которых и хранятся все текстуры. Движок **UE 5**. Много что перепробовал, но так и не смог открыть эти файлы.
Пробовал Game Extractor, но он тоже не смог открыть. Хотя я и установил ему ffmpeg и quickBMS, которые он требовал.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Сходите на форум, где занимаются моддингами, взломами и т.п. Там вам всё расскажут. Этот сайт немного не о том.